# iOS JavaScript Video - webkitCancelFullScreen(); does not work

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode

I'm trying to exit full screen after playing a video in Xcode simulator through web view from html page using JavaScript but it does not work.

I'm using below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function finishVideo() {

       var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

        myVideo.webkitCancelFullScreen();

    }

    // add listener function to ended event -->

    function myAddListener(){

    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

    myVideo.addEventListener('ended',finishVideo,false);


    }

  </script>

 </head>

<body onLoad="myAddListener()">

  <video controls

  src="http://homepage.mac.com/qt4web/A-chord.m4v">

   </video>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
```

instead of:

```
myVideo.webkitCancelFullScreen();
```

this works for me...

Comment: hi Musefan, `document.webkitCancelFullScreen();` works on webkit but `document.mozCancelFullScreen();` doesn't work on Firefox. It makes an attempt to close but then stays at fullscreen. Any thoughts about this bug in Firefox?